# Unramified morphism of schemes: why is "finite" put in parentheses in the statement of this proposition

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

Here is a proposition in the book *Neron Models* giving various equivalent definitions of an unramified morphism of schemes.

[image]

In condition (e), why is finite put in parentheses?  Normally when you state a theorem and write a property in parentheses, that is done to remind the reader that this property is *always* the case.  But here, I see no reason why $\kappa(x)$ should be a finite extension of $\kappa(s)$.

In the affine case, if $\phi: A \rightarrow B$ is an algebra map of finite presentation (so $B$ is the quotient of a polynomial ring $A[t_1, ... , t_n]$ by a finite generated ideal), $\mathfrak P$ is a prime of $B$, and $\mathfrak p = \phi^{-1}\mathfrak P$, there is no reason that the induced map

$$A_{\mathfrak p}/\mathfrak p A_{\mathfrak p} \rightarrow B_{\mathfrak P}/\mathfrak P B_{\mathfrak P}$$
be a finite extension of fields, or even a finitely generated extension of fields.

Comment: Maybe this is precisely the point of your question, but isn't $B_{\mathfrak{P}}/\mathfrak{P}B_{\mathfrak{P}}$ a finitely generated $A_{\mathfrak{p}}/\mathfrak{p}A_{\mathfrak{p}}$-algebra? (It seems like this should follow from the fact that $B$ is a finitely generated $A$-algebra, but maybe I'm mistaken.) Once we have this, Zariski's lemma guarantees that this is a finite extension of fields.

Comment: Hmm..I don't think so.  If $A = k$, $B = k[t_1, ... , t_n]$, and $\mathfrak P$ is any nonmaximal prime ideal of $B$, then $k \rightarrow B_{\mathfrak P}/\mathfrak PB_{\mathfrak P}$ has transcendence degree equal to the dimension of $B/\mathfrak P$.

Comment: But maybe we can say that the field extension is finitely generated (finite transcendence degree with a finite algebraic extension at the top)

Comment: That example fails the condition on the generation of the maximal ideal. The maximal ideal on the $A$ side is zero, while the maximal ideal on the $B$ side is nonzero.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We'll show that any of the conditions that are not (e) imply that the given field extension is finite. We assume that the equivalence of (a)-(d) has already been proven.

Let $k=\kappa(s)$. By (d) and the fact that locally of finite presentation is stable under base change, we may assume $S=\operatorname{Spec} k$. By (c) and the fact that for a $k$-scheme $X$ the local dimension of $X\times_kX$ at $(x,x)$ is twice the local dimension of $X$ at $x$, we know that the local dimension of $X$ at $x$ must be zero, or in other words that $x$ is an isolated point of $X$. By $X\to S$ locally of finite presentation, we can pick an affine open neighborhood of $x$ of the form $\operatorname{Spec} k[x_1,\cdots,x_n]/(f_1,\cdots,f_m)$, and since $x$ is an isolated point of $X$, we know that in fact $x$ is the spectrum of a field extension of $k$ of the form $k[y_1,\cdots,y_p]/(g_1,\cdots,g_q)$. In particular, this implies that $\kappa(x)$ is a finite extension of $k=\kappa(s)$.

On the other hand, one does need the finite extension property when proving the implication that (e) implies the other conditions - if we do not require it, the extension of fields $k\subset k(x)$ clearly has $\Omega_{k(x)/k}\neq 0$.